# Predicting the next output of Java Random with bound of 32

Tags: random-number-generator

I'm trying to predict the next output of random numbers (bounded from 0 to 32) generated by the java.util.Random class. The code is shown below:

```
Random random = new Random();
int first = random.nextInt(32);
int second = random.nextInt(32);
int third = random.nextInt(32);
```

I know that Java's Random class uses a LCG with a 48-bit seed. Given the values of `first` and `second`, how can I find the value of `third`?

Comment: Count the amount of information (bits) that you know, and the amount of information that you would need to know to find the state of the generator (and thus answer the the question as asked with certainty).

Comment: The [specification of the Java Random class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next(int)) gives the parameters of the LCG

Answer (score 1):

since your bound is a power of two its not that hard...
(It takes a bit of brute force but its not that bad)

```
public static long getSeedWithBoundPowerOfTwo(ArrayList<Integer>
samples, int bound) {
     int b = nextIntRecreate(bound,samples.get(0));//lowest possible seed
 
     while (true) {
         if (isRight(b,bound,samples)) {
             return b;
         }
         b++;
     } }
```

Here is my `isRight` method:

```
private static boolean isRight(long seed,int bound ,ArrayList<Integer> samples) {
        Random r = new Random(seed);
        for (int i = 0; i < samples.size(); i++) {
            if (r.nextInt(bound) != samples.get(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And here is my `nextIntRecreate` method:

```
private static int nextIntRecreate(int bound,int r) {
     int m = bound - 1;
         if ((bound & m) == 0) {
             int l =(bound/r) << 31;
             return (bound * l) >> 31;
         }
    return -1;
}
```

`getSeedWithBoundPowerOfTwo` takes samples (in your case list with `first`,`second` and `third`) and bound (in your case `32`)

Note that `getSeedWithBoundPowerOfTwo` won't work with any bound that isn't power of two.

Comment: I bet this does not work in the setup of the question, with only two 5-bit samples. Plus it's brute force, and not optimized on top of that.

Comment: Independently, `nextIntRecreate` is wrong; when `bound` is a power of two (as in the question), it does a division by zero for `r = 0`, and always returns `0`when `r > bound/2`. Also: this optimization is possible, and effective, but requires to take as unknown the state _after_ the first sample, but the rest of the code does not.